# See if left mouse button is held down in the OnMouseMove event

Tags: c#, winforms, onmousemove

How do I detect if the left mouse button is being held down in the `OnMouseMove` event for a control?

Comment: on what platform? the solution is different for WinForms, Silverlight and WPF, etc.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your eventhandler for the OnMouseMove event should recieve a `MouseEventArgs` that should tell you if the left button is pressed

```
private void mouseMoveEventHandler(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
   if(e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
   {
     //do left stuff
   }
   else 
   {
     // do other stuff
   }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Simply have a boolean set to true when the left mouse button is held and set it to false when its released.

If you check the condition of the bool when you fire the OnMouseMove event then you will be able to find out if its held down or not.

**Psuedo code:**

```
private bool isDown;

MouseDown()
{
   isDown = true;
}

MouseUp()
{
   isDown = false;
}
OnMouseMove()
{
   if(isDown)
   {
       //Do something...
   }
}
```

Comment: Concerning e.g. Blazor app: This way you can not capture cases when mouse button is released outside of the component receiving the events or even outside of the web browser! Then your isDown remains true until next mouse click on the component...